# Why can't I vote this answer?

Tags: bug

[Why it took an army of physicists, working on a huge complex, so long to produce a working nuclear device, while it seems so easy in theory?](https://hsm.stackexchange.com/a/6839/65)

The vote buttons on this accepted answer is grey out, while other vote buttons on other answers or the question are clickable.

Comment: I'm not able to reproduce this. Can you try again, and maybe show a screenshot of what it looks like to you?

Comment: turn out it's because of a mysterious script. But that's still weird though because other questions work fine